# Need to write a batch file job

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch job file to keep two folder in sync.

Inputs : Source and Destination folder names.
senario :

1. If the destination folder/subfolder is not found – create and proceed
2. If the files are already present in both the folders Compare and overwrite destination file if timestamp/size differs.
3. If the file not present in source and present in destination, delete the destination file.

kindly help me to write the batch job.

Thanks Vikram

Comment: on which platform ? using which language ?

Comment: [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) might handle the job pretty well...

Comment: @AdrienPlisson batch is a language, and it runs on DOS and Windows

Answer (score 3):

A batch file written by a self-professed inexperienced user - even run periodically - is not a good replacement for a sync tool like [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) or even the [Briefcase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307885) built into Windows.  [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) looks a good bet.

Comment: Or robocopy which also ships with vista/7